# Prove that a general monomial curve is smooth

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves

> Let $k$ be a field, $n_1<n_2<\cdots<n_r$ positive integers, and $C:=\{(t^{n_1},...,t^{n_r})\mid t\in k\}\subset \mathbb{A}^r$. Show that $C$ is a smooth curve iff $n_1=1$.

This is what I've done:

If $n_1=1$, then we can find $a_1,...,a_r\in\mathbb{Z}$ such that $1=a_1n_1+...+a_rn_r$.

Define $f:k\rightarrow C$ by $t\to (t^{n_1},...,t^{n_r})$ which is surjective.

Define $g:\mathbb{A}^r\rightarrow k$ by $(t_1,...,t_r)\to t_{1}^{a_1}t_{2}^{a_2}...t_{r}^{a_r}$.

It is clear that $C\simeq k$, and then $C\simeq \mathbb{A}^1$, we have that $C$ is smooth.

This last affirmation, about the smoothness of $C$ came from the fact that $dim C=1$?

And for the other implication, how can I prove that $n_1=1$?

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know about the Jacobian criteria for smoothness?

Comment: Dear Irene, "The other implication"  is  **FALSE**: see my answer.

Comment: Is a monomial affine curve a algebraic set?

Comment: @Bruno,if you want to ask a question, please ask a questing using the page http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 1):

a) If $t_1=1$ then $C$ is is the graph $C=Gr(f)\subset \mathbb A^{1}\times \mathbb A^{r}=\mathbb A^{r}$ of the regular function $$f:\mathbb A^1\to \mathbb A^{r-1}:t\mapsto (t^{n_2},...,t^{n_r})$$ Thus it is, like all graphs, isomorphic to the source of $f$, namely $\mathbb A^1$, and thus certainly is smooth.

b) If $t_1\gt 1$ then $C$ might be non-smooth as in the example $C_1:=\{(t^{2},t^{3})|t\in k\}\subset \mathbb{A}^2$.
But it may also be smooth as in the case $C_2:=\{(t^{2},t^{4})|t\in k\}\subset \mathbb{A}^2$ (if $k$ is algebraically closed) since $C_2$ is then just  the smooth parabola $y=x^2$.
So the "only if" part of your statement is **FALSE**.

Comment: I see that is a parabola on a graphic, but like an algebraic set each point pass through it two times, so every point is singular and so that is not a smooth curve..right?

Comment: Dear Irene, a set is a set and you asked about the **set** $C$. That the map $\mathbb A^1\to C_2$ is not bijective (if $char.k\neq 2$) and thus even less an isomorphism does not prevent its image $C_2$ from being as smooth  as a baby's skin. I agree however  that these relations between morphisms and their images are rather subtle and might  not always be  analysed in sufficient detail in textbooks or courses .